# ConTeXt doesn't implement some Knuth TeX primitives?

Tags: context, plain-tex, primitives

I try to use new TeX format ConTeXt, but I find that some TeX primitives don't act  any more. How sad I am when I find that.

An simple example is that in plain TeX, we can set the spaces between paragraphs like this

```
    \font\twelverm=cmr12
    \twelverm
    \parskip=14pt
    The first paragraph.\par
    The second paragraph.
    \bye
```

Unfortunately, when I do the same in ConTeXt it do nothing. It only support `\setupwhitespace` but not the original `\parskip`.

I am a newbie in ConTeXt, I only want to know why.

Comment: If you want to write plain TeX, use plain - not ConTeXt.

Comment: @morbusg \parindent and \parskip have very different meaning.

Comment: @morbusg: I really feel so sorry about that. Indeed, It should be `\parskip` in the example rather that `\parindent`.

Comment: @TimLi: No worries! `:-)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the engine level, all formats use the same primitives (when using the same engine). However, each format may rename these and may also implement all, some or none of the plain TeX macros defined by the plain TeX format on top of the engine. Both ConTeXt and LaTeX2e implement some of the TeX primitives, but not all of them. For example, LaTeX users will expect `\end` to be a command to create an environment, as that format stores the `\end` primitive as `\@@end`. ConTeXt is the same: it implements it's own set of commands. As pointed out in a comment, if you want every plain TeX macro and TeX primitive, use plain.

Comment: Maybe I am subjective, but sometimes I have to use some TeX primitives like `\hbox`, `\vbox` to achieve something, for instance, when designing the chapter title. How can I know what TeX primitives are permited? The reference manual hasn't enough information about this.

Comment: @TimLi This is an issue in both LaTeX2e and ConTeXt: there are places where primitives are needed, but are not documented. I'm afraid you have to 'suck it and see'. As you say you are a beginner in ConTeXt, I'd say you should look for 'native' methods first.

Comment: Yeah, maybe users like me have to do that in order to make the codes work exactly.

Comment: @TimLi: Whenever ConTeXt overwrites a TeX primitive, it saves the original using `\normal....`. So, you can always access the original primitives. But just having access to original primitives is not enough. In your example, the reason that `\parskip` does not work is because ConTeXt resets it to the value of `\setupwhitespace` at the end of each paragraph.

Comment: @Aditya:Now, I get the reason:-), but where can I get these details?

Comment: @TimLi I am afraid that the details are only available in the sources. ConText user manual only describes `\setupwhitespace` command so that a user does not have to worry about `\parskip`. Maybe you can write a migration guide for plain tex users.

Comment: @Aditya good idea! A migration guide for plain tex users. But maybe this has to wait for a period of time when I really get familiar with ConTeXt.

Answer (score 5):

ConTeXt also knows `\parskip` like all other primitives:

```
\starttext
foo\par    
bar \parskip=2cm \par
baz \par
foobar
\stoptext
```

However, it makes more sense to use the ConTeXt specific macros

Comment: Indeed, it works, but only between `bar` and `baz`. Following your advice, I will use the better `\setupwhitespace`.